c macro concatenate with function and file name
is it possible to generate a WHERE_AM_I macro in c like below:
i'd like to see if we can auto get some values in pre-define macro.
#define FOO1_AAA 1
#define FOO2_BBB 2

#define WHERE_AM_I.  ???

Void foo1()    (in file AAA)
{
    printf(“%d\n”, WHERE_AM_I);
}

// Print: 1

Void foo2() (in file BBB)
{
    printf(“%d\n”, WHERE_AM_I);
}

// Print:2

define as another macro seems not wokring, i am thinking define it as a function.
#define GEN(FILE, FUNC, VAL) inline int FILE##_##FUNC(){return VAL;}
GEN(myfile, myfunc, 10)

printf("%d\n", myfile_myfun());
// it print 10;

// but i try to add 
#define GET_PP(A, B)    A##_##B
#define GET_VV GET_PP(__FILE__, __func__)
GEN(myfile, myfunc)

void myfunc(){    // in myfile
printf("%d\n", GET_VV);
}
// this does not work

is there way to do this? let macro to generate the function string?

C have a predefined macro __FILE__ to get the file-name as a string. Then there's the __func__ special variable to get the function name. But there's no way to translate that (at compile-time) to an arbitrary number.

If you can use C++20 then there is std::source_location

And when you ask a C-language question, please don't add irrelevant language tags. C++ is a totally different language.

You can also use __LINE__ which will give you the line number

Which file that a function is located inside is not information available to the pre-processor, so there is no way to generate such macros.
There are two standardized strings available at compile time: __FILE__ and __func__. These may be used to print the name of a function and the file path to where the source file is located. But you cannot generate pre-processor macros based on those.
For example
void foo1 (void)
{
    printf("%s is in %s", __func__, __FILE__);
}

Gives output:
foo1 is in /app/example.c

So if you wish to print a certain integer given a certain file, you have to do it in run-time with some manner of look-up table where you search for the file name.
